# IBM MQ version 7.5 error AMQ7472: Object %CHLBATCH.706, type scratchpad damaged

Tags: ibm-mq

We are currently having an issue with an MQ Cluster were a CLUSSDR channel is going into retry as the receiving MQ object is showing as damaged.

Configuration is many QMGR's (STAT00-11) sending messages to the Cluster of 4 QMGR's, 2 FullRepos (HUB01-02  and 2PartialRepos HUB03-04)

Problem is that on the STAT02 QMGR the CLUSSDR channel to HUB01 is in a retry state
with the MQ log error;

- AMQ9506: Message receipt confirmation failed.

and on HUB01 the MQ log errors;

- AMQ7472: Object %CHLBATCH.706, type scratchpad damaged. (many)
- AMQ9999: Channel 'TO_HUB01' to host 'server02 (n.n.n.n)' ended abnormally.
- AMQ9588: Program cannot update queue manager object.    (single instance)
- AMQ9587: Program cannot open queue manager object       (many)

I have now stopped the CLUSSDR on STAT02 to HUB01 and there is no longer any log entries, however as the QMGR's have linear logging the log files are not being released on the HUB01 QMGR

this has introduced a new error

- AMQ7084: Object syncfile, type syncfile damaged.

which is filling up the disk.

I have so far tried to recover the damaged object, the command used was on the HUB01 QMGR

- rcrmqobj  -m HUB01 -t channel TO_STAT02

and this returned the result, *AMQ7085: Object TO_STAT02, type channel not found.*, although the following results contradict this;

- DIS CLUSQMGR(STAT*) CHANNEL

outputs a list of all the STAT* QMGR's which includes the TO_STAT02 channel

and the channel status

- DIS CHS(TO_STAT*) STATUS

shows all the channels in a RUNNING state, including the supposed non-existent TO_STAT02

Anyone had similar issues please, note that this is the second occurrence we have had in the last month to different clusters and last time we had to take the drastic action of rebuilding the QMGR once the disk space was exhausted and the QMGR crashed

Answer (score 2):

```
rcrmqobj -m HUB01 -t syncfile
```

is the correct way to rebuild a corrupt syncfile and if using linear logging this will also repair any damaged scratchpad objects. Damaged scratchpad objects should only ever occur through operational or filesystem error, for example if files were deleted or partially restored from backup and so having a large number is something that you should try and identify the root cause.

`rcrmqobj -t channel` will be able to recover damage to channel object definitions, but it is the synchronization data and its index (syncfile) that is damaged/missing. TO_STAT02 sounds like it is a cluster sender that MQ clustering maintains from information shared within the cluster - you can check on whether a cluster channel has a local channel definition using DEFTYPE on DISPLAY CLUSQMGR.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and I have tried both the rcrmqobj -t channel and -t syncfile however neither worked, strangely both replied with an error of 0... Due to the fact the active logs were increasing at a rate that we had no option to rebuild the QMGR before we had exhausted the disk space. We do run a save QMGR script daily which calls dmpmqcfg for both the MQ objects and the setmqaut, so we did have a pair of files to build from. All rebuilt and good now.